# Positioning an easygui.enterbox or easygui.multenterbox

Tags: python, easygui

Is there a way to specify the position of an `easygui.enterbox` or `easygui.multenterbox` on the screen?

And hopefully to read the current position if the user moves the window?  I have an infinite loop asking for user input and want to keep the window in the same place if the user moves it rather than having it return to the default location on the screen.

I'm using Easygui 0.95 with Python 2.7.1 on MacOS Lion.

Perhaps I can get a pointer to a more complete documentation of all parameters and functionality than what I've found so far.

Comment: You can download docs or use them online e.g, [`easygui.enterbox()`](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/download/version_0.96/doc/epydoc/easygui-module.html#enterbox)

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do it. As a workaround you could patch `easygui.rootWindowPosition`:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import easygui

# calculate window position
root = Tk()
pos = int(root.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.5), int(root.winfo_screenheight() * 0.2)
root.withdraw()
rootWindowPosition = "+%d+%d" % pos

# patch rootWindowPosition
easygui.rootWindowPosition = rootWindowPosition
print(easygui.enterbox())
```